# What is $log( b,a)$ according to google?

Tags: logarithms

I expected that $log(b, a)$ represents $log_ba$.  However this is not what google calculates for you if you type that into the search bar.  For example, google says $log(4,2) \approx 0.62324929039$.  What is it calculating in this case?

Comment: It appears to be $\log 4.2$. Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In google calculator, "," is mapped to "." and $log(b,a)$ represents $log_{10}{b.a}$

Comment: Of course.  That should have been obvious.